# How do you do this list operations in an efficient way in Dart (Bloc/Flutter)?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, bloc

I have BLoC with the following state which contains 2 words ,

```
// 2 words are fixed and same length.
// in word_state.dart
abstract class WordState extends Equatable 
  const WordState(this.quest, this.answer, this.word, this.clicked);
  final List<String> wordA; // WordA = ['B','A','L',L']
  final List<String> wordB; // WordB = ['','','','']
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [wordA,wordB];
}
```

I want to ADD and REMOVE letters.

```
// in word_event.dart
class AddLetter extends WordEvent {
  final int index;
  const AddLetter(this.index);
}
class RemoveLetter extends WordEvent {
  final int index;
  const RemoveLetter(this.index);
}
```

**1.ADD:**
If I select the index of 'L' in wordA, then I add the letter 'L' in the first occurrence of '' (empty) in wordB.

```
// in word_bloc.dart 
void _onLetterAdded(AddLetter event, Emitter<WordState> emit) {
  final b = [...state.wordB]; 
  b[b.indexOf('')] = state.wordA[event.index];
  emit(WordLoaded(state.wordA, b));
}
//wordB, ['','','',''] into ['L','','','']
```

**2.REMOVE:**
If I deselect the index of 'L' in wordA, then I remove the last occurence of letter 'L' in wordB and shift the right side letters to left

```
 void _onLetterRemoved(RemoveLetter event, Emitter<WordState> emit) {
    final b = [...state.wordB];
    final index = b.lastIndexOf(state.wordA[event.index]);
    for (int i = index; i < 4 - 1; i++) { 
      b[i] = b[i + 1];
    }
    b[3] = '';
    emit(WordLoaded(state.wordA, b));
  }
}
// What i am trying to
// ['B','L','A','L']
// if index is 1 then ['B','A','L','']
```

This code is working fine, But I want to do the list operations in efficient way.

Comment: I'd say you missed List.insert and List.removeAt... they directly do what you're looking for and they are built-in.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I don't want to remove any element at specific position. Just need change the value. removeAt will reduce the size of the array. while adding letter, I replace the first empty string with letter. for remove, I just change the value of last occurence of the letter with right elements and and change the last element with empty string. so size of the array will not be change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please check this code understand it and run it on dart pad.

```
  List<String> wordA=['B','A','L','L'];
  List<String> wordB=['','','',''];

  List<String> wordBAll=['B','L','A','L'];
  void main() {
  wordB.insert(0,wordA[2]);
  wordBAll.removeAt(wordBAll.length-1);
  print(wordB);
  print(wordBAll);
```

}

Comment: removeAt will reduce the size of the array

Comment: if you want to increase just use insert it will increase size of the array and you will be able to insert anywhere you want.